# How to determine the strongest oxyacid of chlorine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

> Which is the strongest acid here?
>
> - $\ce{HClO}$
> - $\ce{HClO2}$
> - $\ce{HClO3}$
> - $\ce{HClO4}$

I found [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22056/which-of-the-following-is-the-strongest-base), didn't really get the first answer, but [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/22060/16632) in particular seemed interesting.

Apparently, you calculate a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ for each substance.

According to [this website](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ecrg2133/Files/CambridgeIA/Chemistry/AcidityBasicitykPa.pdf).

$$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = -\log_{10}K_\mathrm{a}$$

I need to find out $K_\mathrm{a}$ then. From what I understand $K_\mathrm{a}$ is obtained from dividing the concentrations of products by the concentrations of reagents. However, how am I supposed to do so if I am not given any equilibrium reactions?

Comment: [Evans'](http://evans.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf) and [Bordwell's](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/index.htm) $p\mathrm{K_a}$ tables have a large amount of data on different compounds. Other sources are also available but these are two of the best that I know.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39451/how-to-assess-the-strength-of-the-acid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such questions you're supposed to know certain rules of acidity. You can find some of them on [this page](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch11/factors.php). In your case fourth rule, concerning oxoacids, is relevant and as you can see there, it's described on this very case. More precise formulation is so called Pauling's Rule described [here](http://chemistrytextbookcrawl.blogspot.com/2013/02/paulings-rules.html). In general the more oxo groups connected to central atom, the more acidic compound.

Related: [How are Pauling's rules applied to Nitric acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/29131)