# How to determine the strongest oxyacid of chlorine without being given the acid dissociation constant data?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I was told to find the strongest and weakest acids out of $\ce{HCl, HClO, HClO2, HClO3}$, and $\ce{HClO4}$. I knew that $\ce{HClO}$ was the weakest but was stuck between $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{HClO4}$ for the strongest (as these are both strong acids). Is there a way to find the relative strength of strong acids **without being given the $K_\mathrm{a}$ or $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$?** Or would I just have to have memorized that $\ce{HClO4}$ is generally stronger than $\ce{HCl}$?

Comment: As for your question, I don’t *think* there is any way to compare the two since there are no real analogies you can use. But I’m not sure enough to actually call this an answer.

Comment: Truthfully a lot of "facts" like this are asked in class tests/problems. In the real world if you use those chemicals then you just know, if you don't use them a lot you then you just look the data up. It is easy to rationalize HClO, HClO2, HClO3 and HClO4. You recognized HCl would be an odd-ball. *sigh* for now you'll just have to memorize it...

Comment: Actually, some people would say that $\ce{HClO3}$ is a strong acid too. I don't think there's a real way to compare $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{HClO4}$. There are some empirical rules for estimating the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of an oxoacid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant#Factors_that_affect_pKa_values but clearly they do not apply to $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: Related: [How to determine which substance is the strongest base/acid?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35284/7951)