# Among HClO4 and HClO2 which is the stronger acid if we do not know Ka values?

Tags: acid-base

I have two acids: $\ce{HClO4}$ and $\ce{HClO2}$ how do I determine which is the strongest acid without knowing $K_a$? The two hydrogens are bound both to an oxygen so there isn't anything to differentiate them, how can I  proceed?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40676/relative-strength-of-strong-acids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{HClO4}$  is stronger acid due to the formation of more stable conjugate base. Also there are more number electronegative oxygen atoms in case of $\ce{HClO4}$ , so acidity should be more.